# Need help getting Google maps directionsPanel to display in a FancyBox

Tags: javascript, google-maps, fancybox

I am currently working on a small piece of functionality for a website. Basically I want to display a map of a port on the page and allow the user to enter their address below it in order to find directions. Once they hit a get directions link, a fancy box will open with the contents being a div containing Google's directionsPanel.

Here are the issues I am running into.
- The calcRoute() function is called onClick of the link. Therefore the div has not been filled previously. The result? On first click the fancybox generates empty. On the second it generates like it is supposed to. One solution I came up with is to manually set the size of the div. However this creates scrolling and styling issues I would rather avoid.

Here is my code (Note this is a small page I created to test my code before porting over to our actual site):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var manhattanPort = new google.maps.LatLng(40.767899, -73.995825);
var myHouse = new google.maps.LatLng(40.419866, -74.152263);
var geoCoder;

  function initialize() {
     geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var mapOptions = {
      center: manhattanPort,
      zoom:14,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directionsPanel"));
  }

  function calcRoute(){
      var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
      var end = manhattanPort;
      var request = {
          origin: address,
          destination: end,
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      };

      geoCoder.geocode( {'address':address}, function(results,status){
          if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
              map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          } else{
              alert("Geocode was not succesful for the following reason: " + status);
          }
      });


      directionsService.route(request, function(result, status){
          if( status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
              directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
          }
      });

  }


function doClear(theText){
    if (theText.value == theText.defaultValue){
        theText.value = ""
    }
}


</script>


 </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
<table align="right">
<tr>
<td align="right" width="330" height="380">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</td>
</t
</table>     
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td align="center">
<div>
    <input name="start_address" id="address" type="text" value="Enter An Address To Get Directions" onFocus="doClear(this)" size="100"/>
    <!-- <input type="button" value="Get Directions" onClick="calcRoute();"/> -->
    <a class="fancybox" href="#directionsPanel" onClick="calcRoute();">Get Directions</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<div id="directionsPanel"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Now obviously I am missing the scripts for the fancybox itself. Let me know if providing those would help.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Call `$.fancybox.update()` in the callback of `directionsService.route()`

Comment: directionsService.route(request, function(result, status){
     if( status ==     google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
     }
     $.fancybox.update();
         });

Like this?

Comment: No, directly after `directionsDisplay.setDirections(result); `

Comment: That did not fix my problem. The fancybox is still opening with an empty div, then once you close the fancybox it fills the div. So a second opening of the fancybox displays the appropiate directionsPanel.

Comment: try to use a short delay: `setTimeout(function(){$.fancybox.update();},50);`   http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/hQef9/